# Issue with KafkaStreams metadataForKey in particular instance alone

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We are  using KafkaStreams in our test instances(ClusterTest) and use metadataForKey to get the particular instance where the key was residing in our store. This was working fine in the test instances. However, when we moved into production instances(ClusterProd) this method started returning null even though the store had the data for the key. We were able to confirm that the key was present in the store since our Stream operations were working fine. However, the end-point we created to get the current value across the instances fails since it is not able to get the metadata information.

We are getting the metadata information as below. The store name is the on both the Test and Prod clusters:
kafkaStreams.metadataForKey(storeName, key, new StringSerializer())

From the server logs I see that the application.server property has been set as required with the appropriate server instance detail.

My question here is, is this method controlled by the cluster specific configuration, since it is working in one cluster but not in another. our infrastructure team mentions that this is an application issue. However, the code has not changed across the clusters, so my assumption is the error cannot be on the code side.

UPDATE: What we observed from additional logs was that allMetadata was returning the required details. It had 3 entries(we are running on 3 instances) and had the host details as expected. Is there any reason why this is not coming in the metadataForKey option?

Comment: If `allMetadata()` return it, but `metadataForKey()` does not, it sound like a bug.

Comment: Yes.. raised a jira here : https://issues.apache.org/jira/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/KAFKA-10843